# Ansible: Difference between the apt module and command: apt-get -y install X (module)

Tags: ansible

Consider these YAML tasks which are based on two different parts of some locally-executed Ansible playbook [I read here](https://www.tricksofthetrades.net/2017/10/02/ansible-local-playbooks/):

```
- name: Update the apt package-index cache i.e. apt-get update
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: Ensure aptitude is installed
  command: apt-get install -y aptitude
```

As an Ansible newbie, I recognize two different Ansible modules here: `apt` and `command`.

Why did the OP use both `apt: update_cache=yes` and `command: apt-get install -y` instead using the `apt` module in both tasks?

<sub>Note: I myself no longer use `apt-get` but `apt` even in regular Bash scripting.</sub>

Comment: I don't think so and I won't argue. I want no discussion with you after I got the impression you don't want to talk seriously with me here given the lies you wrote about me. FYI, I ask questions here and in Unix&Linux Stackexhcange while Reading the good book by Geerling "Ansible for DevOps" although I'm not a DevOp and learning Ansible bits by bits in an orderly way and had successions and will succeed in what I'll succeed. I have no time for sarcasm and what I recognize as violations of StackExhcnage code of conduct. I call upon you not to reply to my questions are. I missed the `-y` there.

Comment: That's no big deal. I actually improved the question making the tasks more loyal to the OP. I don't want to go on with this conversation after your attitude towards me which I found uncommunal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In other words, why not both be done with an apt module?

We can't say for certain, but likely it's just a mistake coming from ignorance. The latter command can be fully implemented using the Ansible apt module, and you should always prefer that over `command`; `command` exists as an escape for when there isn't a module for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

> TL;DR: Ansible modules like `apt` can be mostly implemented with
>   `command` module, but you lose error checking. Using command is usually sign of a lack of experience with ansible.

To answer this question it is best to look at the [code implementing the apt module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/packaging/os/apt.py) in ansible. What you can see is that most of the features of the module are implemented by constructing an appropriate `apt-get` command and executing it, then handling error conditions and presenting them in ansible data structures. Sometimes depending on options the command can be quite complex. In two exceptions for upgrade, in case it is *full-upgrade* or *safe-upgrade* it would use `aptitude` command instead of `apt-get`.

Of course, the implementation of the module can change going forward, but you should be able to rely on it doing essentially the same thing. On the other hand, if `apt-get` changes in some way or returns new unhandled type of errors, you will need to change your ansible code in case you use `command` module directly. While if you use `apt` module, it is likely the maintainer of the module will implement the new error checking for you.

So in general it is better to use `apt` to `command: apt-get` unless the module won't do something that you absolutely need to do and there is no other way around it.

To do the 2nd task in ansible using apt module do:

```
- name: Ensure some basics
  apt:
    name: aptitude
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question there. Xiong is giving the simple answer. There is no reason for the 2nd to be done through command.